# invalid key form applescript

Tags: applescript

I Have the following code in a program im working on

```
set outPath to "/Users/student/Desktop/Accounts.txt"
set x to text returned of (display dialog "Username" default answer "")
set y to text returned of (display dialog "Password" default answer "")
set RAccounts to (read POSIX file "/Users/student/Desktop/Accounts.txt")
if file path outPath exists
then 
get word 1 
else
```

and then it continues on, but whenever i try to compile it it gives me the following error

> invalid key form

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set outPath to "/Users/student/Desktop/Accounts.txt"
set x to text returned of (display dialog "Username" default answer "")
set y to text returned of (display dialog "Password" default answer "")
try
    set RAccounts to read POSIX file outPath
on error
    -- file outPath does not exist … do things
end try
```

OR

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists POSIX file "/Users/student/Desktop/Accounts.txt" then
        beep
    else
        beep 2
    end if
end tell
```